# Difference between IAM Managed Policy and Managed Policy for Job Functions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

What is the difference between IAM Managed Policy and Managed Policy for Job Functions?

According to this page https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_job-functions.html, [AdministratorAccess](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home#policies/arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess), [ViewOnlyAccess](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home#policies/arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/job-function/ViewOnlyAccess) are both job functions. However, when looking at their ARNs, AdministratorAccess Managed Policy doesn't have `job-function` in it.
e.g.
`arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess` vs `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/job-function/ViewOnlyAccess`

What is actually a job function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically there is no difference. There is nothing special about `job-function`. It is just an [IAM path](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_identifiers.html#identifiers-friendly-names) that AWS chose to use for common people's roles who can access AWS.

When you create your own IAM policies, you can also add those IAM paths to [them](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_identifiers.html#identifiers-friendly-names):

> you could use the nested path `/division_abc/subdivision_xyz/product_1234/engineering/` to match your company organizational structure.